# Planning a one shot for my group for one of my player's birthday

Tags: dnd-5e, encounter-design, one-shot

So one of my player's birthday is coming up soon and it so happens to fall on the day we usually do our sessions. I was planning on doing a one shot based around her Druid character and all my other players agreed so I have most of the encounters and extra little bits included, but I'm at a loss for what to throw at them as the big boss at the end as they cut through most of the monsters/people I throw at them pretty well as a group.

The group consists of:

- Half-orc Barbarian; Path of the Totem Warrior: Bear
- Human Monk; Way of the Shadow
- Halfling; Rogue: Swashbuckler
- Tiefling; Warlock: Hexblade (Pact of the Blade)
- Tabaxi; Druid; Circle of the Land (Forest)

**As a note**
The One-shot is based on a coliseum battle arena, I'm allowing them to level up to 20 for it, so I really want them to have a fun time with the end boss but not kill it too quickly, they are regularly level 14.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat Come here so we can help

Comment: @Pandora, unfortunately SE isn't really suited for broad idea generation, which seems to be the goal of this question. I would recommend the chat room that KDodge linked you to. I think you 20 rep to post, so I've given you an upvote to get you 5 points closer. Alternately, you may wish to try a forum like GitP or another gaming site. If you've a more narrow question focused on whether a specific encounter is balanced for level 20 characters, we can probably better assist you there.

Comment: Can a moderater add her to the RPG chat so we can help? I know they need 20 rep unless a mod helps

Comment: Looks like Pandora just hit 21 reputation :)

Comment: We'll help you out in that chat Pandora